# Eloquent Get higher value of a specific table's column

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Using Eloquent in Laravel,

To get the minimum value of a column this code works:

```
public function getLowestYearBook()
{
    return CV_Outputs::min('book_publication_year');
}
```

But to get the higher value it doesn't work, i'm using 'max' instead of 'min'.

How to get the higher? Thanks!

--------------- Edit:

the problem is I have some rows with "Not defined" text in it, so sorting by desc it returns that row, because letters are "higher" than number.

I fixed it by doing this:

```
public function getHighestYearBook()
{
    return CV_Outputs::all()
    ->where('book_publication_year', '<>', "Not defined")
    ->sortByDesc('book_publication_year')
    ->first()->book_publication_year;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check if the type/value is the same in all rows, because `max` should do the job. But try sorting them in descending order which means highest first and then get the first element like this:

```
CV_Outputs::all()
    ->where('book_publication_year', '!=', 'Not defined')
    ->sortByDesc('book_publication_year')
    ->first();
```

Comment: in that column i have some rows with "Not defined" text in it, so letters come first than "numbers" in descending order.

Comment: Then exclude them. Look at my edit. Ah, I just noticed you already fixed that. You can accept my answer as is the one that you use :) I did not know about the not defined data, before I answered :)